# How to change a project variable using Python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'd like to change the value of a user-defined project variable (can be manually edited in Project Settings | Variables) using the Python console. I tracked down the [setVariable() function in the QgsExpressionContextScope class](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsExpressionContextScope.html) but haven't succeeded in actually changing the variable in the project settings. My code so far:

```
iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().expressionContext().scope(0).setVariable('myvar',1)
```

I guess I'm getting lost in the different expression contexts ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at QgsExpressionContextUtils (https://qgis.org/api/classQgsExpressionContextUtils.html). The method you need is QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable, e.g.

```
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable('myvar','hello world')
```

Comment: What about deleting a variable? I didn't find method for it in `QgsExpressionContextUtils`

Comment: There's no high level API to do this. Possibly you could get away with NULLING the variable (setting it to None), but if not, you need to use QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariables({} ) and reset the whole lot. You'd first need to check QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope() and create a dict of all the variables you want to keep. It's far from ideal - but would also be a trivial addition to the API if you wanted to get involved in QGIS development and send through a pull request on github...

Comment: Thanks @ndawson, it works with your work around to reset with `setProjectVariables(preserved_variables)`
I have checked the C++ code, I hope I can contribute for the functionality.

Comment: [`QgsExpressionContextUtils.removeProjectVariable`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsExpressionContextUtils.html#a538d3af82abc562b3a1c011c04df1eed) exists now!

Comment: There is a new required parameter since QGIS 3.0. See an updated answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222494/how-to-read-user-defined-project-variables-using-python

Answer (score 6):

In QGIS3, the API needs to pass `QgsProject` as the first argument.

It is: `setProjectVariable(project: QgsProject, name: str, value: Any)`

`QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(), 'myvar','hello world')`