# How to read user defined project variables using Python

Tags: pyqgis

I can change user defined project variables by QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable('myvar','hello world')

But how can I access/read this variable in a python script?

Comment: I cannot try this but documentation suggests that there should be a `QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope` method through which you can access that information.

Answer (score 20):

Since QGIS 3.0 you need also to specify the project when setting and reading a variable:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(project,'myvar','Hello World!')
QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(project).variable('myvar')
```

Answer (score 6):

If you set a project variable using:

```
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable('myvar','hello world')
```

You can use the following to read the value of this variable:

```
QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope().variable('myvar')
>>> u'hello world'
```