# Aggregating points within certain distance and keeping all points info using QGIS

Tags: qgis, combine, aggregate

I have a map with many duplicate points and I want to combine those points together into one, based on the name and geographical location (10 meters), is there a way to do this with QGIS, given that I tried the following method:

```
Aggregate > GROUP_BY= geom_to_wkb($geometry)
```

[image]

When doing this, the application merged the duplicate points in the exact same place and did not work within 10 meters

Is there a solution to do this on QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Thank you I forgot about that, I added a screenshot, if there is a better way to group it by Name/Geolocation (10m)/Average distance between duplicate points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is best, but I think it will work. I wasn't able to find a plugin or other way to accomplish all your requirements.

1. DBSCAN [image]
2. Calculate field with a value of Name plus CLUSTER_ID.  Expression something like this,

   Concat("Name",'_',to_string("CLUSTER_ID"))
3. Mean Coordinate(s) with Unique field being your Calculated field.
4. Join the mean coordinate output with your previous output to get the attributes merged.  You can export as well to have a unified layer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great solution and I added a step which is I filled the nulls values in the CLUSTER_ID column with:  

if("CLUSTER_ID" is null,rand(200000,900000), "CLUSTER_ID")  

This is because names that are very far from each other may match and are calculated in Mean Coordinate(s)  

Regards

Comment: Glad it worked.  A wildly random number is a neat solution for the null values.  Very quick.  For a cleaner solution, have a look at QGIS project variables.  You could set and increment a variable similar what's described here, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222494/how-to-read-user-defined-project-variables-using-python

Comment: Yes, it is not a clean solution, but the nulls I had were few and it was suitable for me, and I did not know a way to do otherwise, I remember in Excel you can put a number and then increment it and it does not repeat.