# eval() statement in QGIS data defined override expression editor gives unexpected results

Tags: qgis, data-defined-override

In QGIS I've set up some project variables called `rv_farbe1`, `rv_farbe2` and so on. The contain color values in html notation like `'#ff0080'`.

[image]

Now in rule base labels I would like to setup *data defined override* by selecting the text color based on an attribute value `sektor_lfd_nr`. The idea is to concatenate a string `@rv_farbe` and the `sektor_lfd_nr` and evaluate the result in order to access the variable value like

```
eval('@rv_farbe' ||  "sektor_lfd_nr")
```

As far as I understand, in expression editor preview I should get the color value, but preview (german: 'Ausgabevoransicht') displays nothing:

[image]

Furthermore, the text with *data defined override* set for it's color does not display.

Both using the variable directly (`@rv_farbe1`) as well as using the html style color code directly (`'#ff00bb'`) works, so do I miss something about `eval()` statement, or what might be wrong here?

Comment: not sure how to do this with vanilla expressions. You could use a python function instead, [such as this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/236642/55203) to take a field name and look up (then return) the corresponding variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a night of forensics, I found that the problem is not the `eval()` statement.

The Layer for which I tried what I described above is based on a PostgreSQL view, which under very special conditions is caused to be empty by a `division by zero` error.

So the message is: The `eval()` statement works fine and can be used to retrieve variable values from a prefix/attribute value combination, i.e. `eval('@rv_farbe'||"sektor_lfd_nr")`

After fixing my view definition, the result is as expected (note the output preview):

[image: [Image 2b added]]