# How to delete user defined project variables using Python

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to delete a variable from QGIS Project variables. I didn't find the functionality in `QgsExpressionContextUtils` (I use it to set a variable).
I also tried to do this:

```
project_context_scope = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope()
project_context_scope.removeVariable('test')
```

It does remove from project_context_scope. But, when I open the QGIS Project properties to see the list of variables, the deleted variable is still exist.

May be I was wrong in getting the instance of `project_context_scope`, since it's not a singleton and `projectScope` create new object.

Comment: Did you try with **del variable_name**? If you have a list: `for var in list:`...`del var`.

Comment: I don't think that will work since the `variable_name` is a string. It's like value mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to do it, after got suggestion from nwadson's [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189075/how-to-change-a-project-variable-using-python/189815?noredirect=1#comment392765_189815)

The idea is using `QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope().variableNames()` to get existing variables. Then iterate which variable that you want to keep. After that, you set it with:

```
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariables(existing_variables)
```

Note: there is no high-level API to delete a project variable for now.

Update: I have implemented the API to do it (like @martin mentioned on the other answer)

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side :)

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 3 this functionality is added, simply use:

```
QgsExpressionContextUtils.removeProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(), 'your_project_variable_name')
```

Comment: ah yes, I ended up implementing the API. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your use case, but one option is since the .qgs file is just xml you could open the file with python and do a simple .replace then save out each line to a new .qgs file, delete old .qgs file, and rename new back to old .qgs filename.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, for my use case, it won't work since the QGIS project is on the fly.

Comment: @ismailsunni, can you expand more what you mean by "it won't work since the QGIS project is on the fly"?

Comment: Ah sorry for not so clear reply. So, in my use case, I do not work with the qgs file, but more in the project variable when we run QGIS. I am not sure, but if we updated the .qgs file, we should reload / refresh the project in QGIS. In my case, I can't do that (or may be it's too complicated)