# Using print composer name in a label

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, title

I want the title (a label) of my map in print composer to automatically contain the name I've given the print composer and also the date that it was created. For example I want it to say 'Really cool map of (print composer name) created on (date the print composer was created).'

I can then use it as a template for lots of other maps which will automatically update with the site name and date created.

I think I need to use the 'Insert an Expression' but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It might be possible to write a Python script that would create and auto-fill a custom variable in the print layout, `@layout_creation_date`, with the current date at the time of creating a new print layout. I couldn't find any similar examples, so you'd have to figure out a lot of new things. This Q&A might help a little bit: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189075/how-to-change-a-project-variable-using-python

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
This is a rad map of [% @layout_name %], created on [%format_date(now(),'dd.MM.yyyy')%]
```

Feel free to browse the field calculator's function-trees, since the help/examples offered are rather easy to understand.

Comment: It's not very exact, `now()` refers to the date when the layout is printed and not when the print composer was created. I don't found a such variable, only the project creation date ... Also, your answer is good but near.

Comment: Hmm, `project_creation_date` doesn't print anything in my case. Haven't found any other option.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the HTML frame.
Add a frame and add an expression like this

```
Really cool map of [% @layout_name %] printed on [% format_date(now(),'dd.MM.yyyy')%]
```

[image]

**UPDATE** (after Erik's comment):

```
Really cool map of [% @layout_name %] printed on [% format_date(@project_creation_date,'dd.MM.yyyy')%]
```

Gives in my case
[image]

Comment: same comment as @Erik 's answer.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps in this case, one should hard code the actual date of creating the map. (I can't see QGIS offering a 'created_date'-option.)