# QGIS Set Project variable in Graphical Modeller

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am trying to update a project variable using the graphical modeller.
I am using the **set project variable** algorithm which runs fine but the behaviour is not as expected. Rather than updating the value of the existing variable the algorithm creates a variable using the value from the old variable and sets that new variables value to the new value.
I have searched for similar issues and found [This Post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189075/how-to-change-a-project-variable-using-python) and I can run the command in the python console and it works fine but I need to do the rest of the processing in the Graphical Modeller

```
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(), 'myvar','hello world')
```

Answer (score 0):

Late, but what you can do:

1. create a script that does what you want by running the python code
2. add the script to your model in the graphical modeler

Comment: I got it working using the set project variable  algorithm. I don't think adding a script to a model is very simple - is there an easy way to do it?